# how to load the second class tableView data in first class view

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

i have two classes class A & B ,In class A i have mapView and one button on clicking that button i want to load the tableView of class B on the map and i also need to set the frame of class B TableView in the class A 
Everything is written without using the storyboards. please help me out thanks in advance.

in ViewDidLoad of Class A

```
 -(void)viewDidload{
    [mapView addSubview:classBViewController.tableView];
   classBViewController.tableView.hidden=YES;
}

-(IBAction)buttonClick{
    classBViewController.tableView.hidden=NO;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply directing to class B's view on Button Click? By using Segue or PushViewController?

Comment: Its Very old project so we are not using any story boards every thing is done programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Delegate or NSNotification.

Here, Delegate is looking better.you can use delegate by following changes.

In class A.h, do following :-

```
@protocol ClassADelegate <NSObject>

- (void)classAButtonClickEvent;
@end
```

and make delegate object for ClassADelegate in class A
@property(nonatomic, strong)    id   *delegate;

In class A.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick{
 if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(classAButtonClickEvent)]) {
            [delegate classAButtonClickEvent];

}
```

And in class B conforms the ClassADelegate and implement classAButtonClickEvent() method of protocol.in that method you can perform changes over your tableview of classB.for ex

```
- (void)classAButtonClickEvent {
    classBViewController.tableView.hidden=NO;
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Tanvi's answer is what you're looking for. Creating a delegate in this situation makes no sense because you already know when the button gets clicked (the IBAction, buttonClick, should fire when the button is tapped, given you have it set up correctly).

Instead of hiding and unhiding the tableview, you should push class B onto a UINavigationController. You also won't need to add the tableView from class B as a subview of the mapView on viewDidLoad with this solution.

Here's an example of what I'm saying:

```
// If you don't already have a navigation controller
-(IBAction)buttonClick {
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
    ClassB *classBViewController = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    [nav pushViewController:classBViewController animated:YES]; 
}    

// If you already have a navigation controller
-(IBAction)buttonClick {
    ClassB *classBViewController = [[ClassB alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:classBViewController animated:YES]; 
}
```